# Pointer of strings stored in linked list

Tags: c

I want to store words from a pointer of char strings in a double linked list. My function for storing the words in the char strings works perfect, but when it comes to storing in the dll elements it doesn't work anymore. I can't understand if there is a problem in the declarative zone of the list (I am new to lists, we just did some theory on them in the class) or with the node changing pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>

int number_of_words (FILE *f) {
char x[1024];
int i=0;
while (fscanf(f, " %1023s", x) == 1) {
    i++;
}
return i;
}

void words (FILE *f, char *words[]) {
char x[1024];
int i=0;
while (fscanf(f, " %1023s", x) == 1) {
    words[i]=strdup(x);
    i++;
}

}

typedef struct node{
int freq;
char *word_string;
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
}node;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

FILE *input=fopen(argv[1], "r+");
if(input==NULL) printf("error in reading from file");
else printf("reading works.\n");
int k=number_of_words(input);

char *word[k];
char *word_unique[k];

rewind(input);
words(input, word);

int j=0,l=0,s=0;

for(j=0;j<k;j++) {
    for (l=0; l<j; l++){
        if (strcmp(word[j],word[l])==0)
            break;
    }

    if (j==l){
        word_unique[s]=word[j];
        s++;
    }

}

int *word_freq[s];

for(j=0;j<s;j++){
    word_freq[j]=0;
}

for(j=0;j<s;j++) {
    for (l=j; l<k; l++){
        if (strcmp(word_unique[j],word[l])==0)
            word_freq[j]++;
    }
}

char *aux=malloc(30*sizeof(char));

for(j=0;j<s;j++){
    for(l=j+1;l<s-1;l++){
        if(strcasecmp(word_unique[j], word_unique[l])>0)
        {
            strcpy(aux,word_unique[j]);
            strcpy(word_unique[j],word_unique[l]);
            strcpy(word_unique[l],aux);

        }
    }
}

node *head, *curr=NULL;
int i=0;
head=NULL;

for(i=0;i<k;i++){
    curr=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr->word_string=word_unique[i];
    curr->freq=word_freq[i];
    curr->next=head;
    head=curr;

}

while(curr) {

    if(curr->word_string!=NULL) printf("%s:%d\n", curr->word_string, curr->freq);
    curr = curr->next;
}

return 0;
}
```

The input file is a text file and it looks like this:
Everything LaTeX numbers for you has a counter associated with it. The name of the counter
is the same as the name of the environment or command that produces the number, except
with no. Below is a list of some of the counters used in LaTeX’s standard document styles
to control numbering.

When I tried to print the unique elements in alphabetical order with their frequency, it actually prints out in reverse order with 4x frequency they actually have. It also separates "numbering." from the others + a new line at the beginning which I don't know where it comes from. This is what it prints:

```
reading works.
0- :2098416
numbering.:4 
you:4
with:4  
used:4
to:4
the:4
The:4
that:4
styles:4
standard:4
some:4
same:4
produces:4
or:4
of:4
numbers:4
number,:4
no:4
name:4
list:4
LaTeX’s:4
LaTeX:4
it.:4
is:4
in:8
has:24
for:16
except:8
Everything:4
environment:4
document:8
counters:4
counter:8
control:8
command:4
Below:4
associated:4
as:4
a:4
\.:4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: 1) You need rewind before `words(input, word);` 2) `words[i]=x;` Need allocate and copy --> `words[i]=strdup(x);` 3) delete `curr->word_string=(char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));` if done (2).

Comment: Please provide the contents of the input file. Also in `while (fscanf(f, " %1023s", x) == 1) {words[i]=x;}` inside `words` function, you are always updating `words[0]`, replacing previous value/content.

Comment: previous my comment (2) `words[i]=strdup(x);` --> `words[i++]=strdup(x);`